# When testing controllers post method how do I mock primary key returned by MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, model-view-controller, moq

My xunit test is failing because the expected Id isn't updated by the database when unit testing.
How do I mock the id/primary key being created by the database?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<AccountReadDto>> CreateAccountAsync(AccountCreateDto createAccountDto)
{
    var account = _mapper.Map<Account>(createAccountDto); // Id is int equal to 0
    await _accountRepo.CreateAccountAsync(account); // repo calls db and updates Id with pk
    _accountRepo.SaveChanges();

    var accountReadDto = _mapper.Map<AccountReadDto>(account);
    return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetAccountByIdAsync), new { AccountId = accountReadDto.AccountId }, accountReadDto);
}

[Fact]
public async Task CreateAccountAsync_NewAccount_ReturnsAccountReadDto()
{
    var expectedAccount = CreateRandomAccount(); // has id
    var createDto = _mapperStub.Map<AccountCreateDto>(expectedAccount); // doesn't have id

    _repoStub
        .Setup(repo => repo.CreateAccountAsync(expectedAccount))
        .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
    var controller = new AccountController(_repoStub.Object, _mapperStub);

    var actionResult = await controller.CreateAccountAsync(createDto);

    var result = (actionResult.Result as CreatedAtRouteResult).Value as AccountReadDto;
    result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(
        expectedAccount,
        options => options.ComparingByMembers<AccountReadDto>().ExcludingMissingMembers() // excluding login info
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code is not correct:

```cs
_repoStub
    .Setup(repo => repo.CreateAccountAsync(expectedAccount))
```

It's setups `CreateAccountAsync` just for case when you will pass `expectedAccount` instance as argument. (After mapping it's not the same). Use `It.IsAny<T>()` to configure method to work with any argument. Then use `Callback<T>(Action<T>)` to access argument passed to mock call:

```cs
_repoStub
    .Setup(repo => repo.CreateAccountAsync(It.IsAny<Account>()))
    .Callback<Account>(a => a.Id = expectedAccount.Id)
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

In that code you configured `CreateAccountAsync` method to return `Task.CompletedTask` and modify incoming argument id to `expectedAccount.Id`.

`Returns(Task.CompletedTask)` can be ommited. (It's default behaviour)

Additional info about `Callback<T>`: [link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqCallbacks.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the additional information :)